# PHP - when creating file with fopen it will add random extension

Tags: php, fopen

When i try to create file with `fopen('../files/report_'.$time.'.xlsx','w');` it will create file with random extension `report_1552395474844.xlsx.M0Vv7Z`.

Can you help?

Comment: can you share your code ?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options.

First: Your code runs and never closes the file. For that time it is considered a temp file which needs to be closed to get its real name. So try closing the file right after writing in it.

Second: You're looking in the wrong folder and an old file which has been created somewhen before

Comment: It only happens when i try to create file with extension .xlsx . When i try .txt or .xls files are created properly